# Multiple Column Confusion

Tags: mysql

I am developing a web based music application. I get struck into a confusion related to MySQL columns.

Problem is like this:
I have album table:
album_id
album_name
album_year
Now the problem is: an album can contains multiple tracks (identified by track_id). Now how to store multiple track id's in album table?
I am novice to MySQL.

Comment: You might benefit from basic relational database tutorial or an SQL tutorial (try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/). The answer to your question is that you're not going to store albums and tracks into same table. Their nature is different and thus they belong to two separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another table, lets name it `album_has_tracks`. 
It has following structure:

```
album_id    track_id
       1           1
       1           2
       1           3
       2           4
       2           5
       2           6
```

That is named `relations` and that is one of the point, that MySQL is named `relational database`. Both of the `album_id` and `track_id` are `foreign keys` and represent columns with their ids. After that, to get the data of the tracks, you have to use `JOIN`. So that are the basic you have to read about.

I would suggest you to read some basic about relational databases, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Comment: glad to help you and have fun in learning basics of relational databases

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some tutorials on relational database design.

You wouldn't store the tracks in the album table, you would create an album tracks table with, for example, track_id, album_id, track_name

The album_id in the tracks table would be set as a foreign key linked to the album table and you would set its value in the track entries to the matching album_id from the album table.

Comment: Your answer is bit theoretical but i understood your point, thanks for your efforts and time.